# How do I run SQL queries on a WordPress web page?

Tags: plugins, mysql, sql

Whenever I Google this it brings up pages related to Database management. However, I want to run this in the actual webpage.

For example:

You go to a webpage where you can practice SQL:

I.e. you have a window where you type:

```
Create table  T1 (
   Id not null,
   Name varchar(60)
);

Insert in T1 (Id, Name) 
values (1, 'john');

Select * from T1;
```

This would give you a single row, two column table 
Where the I'd is 1 and the name is John 
**Id | Name

1  | john**

Thanks!